# Product of a matrix and a tensor

Tags: matrices, tensor-products, products

I need to know how to compute the following product:

$M(x)\frac{\partial M(x)}{\partial x}M(x)$
$\quad$ where $x \in R^{n}$.

Assuming the dimensions of the matrices are compatible,how do we take the product of a matrix $M(x)$ with a tensor $\frac{\partial M(x)}{\partial x}$?

Thanks